# previous tab url in onUpdate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an extension send time that user spend on each tab and my problem is i cant get previous tab url

note : i these codes are in background.js and i've added Tabs and activetab to manjfest.json
my code

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo,tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete" && tab.status == "complete" && tab.url != undefined)
  { 
    clearInterval(mtimer);
    console.log("stoped : "+changeInfo['url']);
    console.log(sec);
    send(serverUrl, previousUrl, sec);
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    console.log("update");
    console.log("updated to : " + tab.url);
    Timmer(start);
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
    start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    tabUrl = tab.url;
    console.log("you are here: " + tabUrl);
    // Timmer(start);
  });
  console.log("stoped "+ tabUrl);
  console.log(sec);
  send(serverUrl, tabUrl, sec);
  clearInterval(mtimer);
});
```

mtimer is a function for count time in sec and with send function send time and url to server

thanks for your helps i need this alot

Comment: You'll have to store tab URLs in a global object, and update it in onUpdated like if (changeInfo.url) tabUrls[tabId] = changeInfo.url

Comment: sir this return current tab url i want the tab changed to new tab , eg: www.google.com update to w3schools i want google

Comment: Prior to the assignment tabUrls[tabId] will contain the previous url.

Comment: tnx sir it works